# How to enable internet access with address resolution to a libvirt VM inside a custom NAT-based network

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, nat, libvirt

I am trying to setup a private network for VMs as prosed on [libvirt networking handbook](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/custom-nat-based-network.html) but the VMs are not able to connect to the internet and resolve domain names.

As following the handbook linked above, I have set up in the Host a so called "Custom NAT-based network":

- Disabled libvirt's default network;
- Created a dummy interface (named `virbr10-dummy`);
- Created a virtual bridge (named `virbr10` with the subnet `10.10.0.0/24`);
- Implemented NAT with `iptables` (please see full iptables rules file below);
- Configured a system-wide instance of `dnsmasq` that ignores the virtual bridge;
- Added a `dnsmasq@virbr10` `systemd` script that gets called by NetworkManager's dispatcher script when the bridge is up.

The Host can ping the guest and vice-versa. The Host is part of a network with internet access (IP `192.168.0.15`) and it is configured to be the gateway for this private LAN for the VMs (IP `10.10.0.1`). A Guest with the IP `10.10.0.10` cannot resolve internet addresses (eg google.com) neither ping IPs on the internet directly (eg `216.58.222.46` for google.com).

---

### Host

File `/var/lib/dnsmasq/virbr10/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
except-interface=lo
interface=virbr10
bind-dynamic
dhcp-range=10.10.0.2,10.10.0.254
dhcp-lease-max=1000
dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/dnsmasq/virbr10/leases
dhcp-hostsfile=/var/lib/dnsmasq/virbr10/hostsfile
dhcp-no-override
strict-order
```

Results from `systemctl status dnsmasq@virbr10.service`:

```
● dnsmasq@virbr10.service - DHCP and DNS caching server for virbr10.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-06-07 09:43:39 -03; 8h ago
 Main PID: 1209 (dnsmasq)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-dnsmasq.slice/dnsmasq@virbr10.service
           └─1209 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -k --conf-file=/var/lib/dnsmasq/virbr10/dnsmasq.conf
```

File `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr10 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 ! -d 10.10.0.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 ! -d 10.10.0.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 ! -d 10.10.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr10 -p udp -m udp -m multiport --dports 53,67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr10 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 53,67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.0/24 -o virbr10 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/24 -i virbr10 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr10 -o virbr10 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr10 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -o virbr10 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

---

### Guest

File `cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 10.10.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iptables` was dead and thus rules were not being executed:

`$ systemctl restart iptables` solved the problem.